# Attachment in RT-Field in read mode not visible

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have got a form which use the following formula inside a hotspot to insert files to rich text fields

```
@If(@IsError(@Command([EditInsertFileAttachment]));
@Do( @Command([EditGotoField];"AttachmentRT"); @Command([EditInsertFileAttachment])); "")
```

After saving the document the attachment  is not visible in read mode. The problem is that I can't reproduce this on other forms. What can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RichText field has set the property "Hide Paragraph when document is ... Opened for reading" in form. That's why the content is only visible in edit mode.

Remove this property in form *and* in RichText field in all documents created with this form.

Comment: No I checked this before. There is no hiding active neigher in richtext field nor in form.

Comment: You're right it was the hide formula in existing documents! Thanks very much